# Upload de imagem com PrimeFaces em servidor TomCat, sendo guardado somente o path da imagem na base de dados

Tags: java, hibernate, primefaces, tomcat

Fala galera.

Sou iniciante em Java e estou fazendo um pequeno projeto Dynamic Web usando PrimeFaces,JSP, Hibernate e TomCat. Basicamente se trata de vários formulários de cadastros e um deles é o cadastro de usuários. A parte do Domain, Bean, DAO e as paginas para listar, cadastrar, editar e excluir já estão prontas e funcionando, porém a tabela de usuário tem um campo para foto(imagem), e é ai que está meu problema.
Quero salvar somente o path da Foto(imagem) na base de dados, e na pagina do usuario quero deixar que eles adicione sua foto, claro. Li muitas coisas no Google de como fazer usando o componente **p:fileUpload**, e confesso que consegui, em partes. O problema é que, eu quero que as imagens sejam salvas da maneira correta, por exemplo em uma pasta /imagens em meu projeto.

**A forma que estou fazendo agora é assim:**
**No Bean**

```
public void upload(FileUploadEvent event) {

    try {
        String realPath = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                .getExternalContext().getRealPath("/");

        // Aqui cria o diretorio caso não exista
        File file = new File(realPath + "/imagens/");
        file.mkdirs();

        byte[] arquivo = event.getFile().getContents();
        String caminho = realPath + "/imagens/"
                + event.getFile().getFileName();

        // esse trecho grava o arquivo no diretório
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(caminho);
        fos.write(arquivo);
        fos.close();

        pathImage = caminho;
        System.out.println("caminho da imagem salva é  = " + caminho);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}`
```

**No arquivo .xhtml**

```
                    <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{checksPicosBean.upload}" fileLimit="1"
                    fileLimitMessage="Excedido Limite de arquivos"
                    cancelLabel="Cancelar" label="Arquivo" uploadLabel="Anexar"
                    invalidFileMessage="Somente arquivos .jpg, .png ou .gif"
                    allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/" value="#{checksPicosBean.imagem}"
                    mode="advanced" skinSimple="true" />
```

O Problema é que ele está salvando em uma pasta no meu disco c: e não em uma suposta pasta do servidor.
Qual seria a maneira correta para fazer isso acontecer? Existe alguma configuração no TomCat que tem que ser feita?
Pretendo disponibilizar esses formulários na web, então gostaria de saber como é a maneira correta para fazer isso funcionar.

Comment: Como está sendo gravado o path atualmente?   O recomendável seria vc gravar em algum diretório do servidor reservado para isso, e fora do contexto da aplicação.

Comment: O Saito tem toda razão, guardar imagens dentro da aplicação é apenas para imagens staticas, o correto é se beneficiar dos diretórios virtuais do Tomcat, onde você cria um arquivo .xml com nome do projeto + jogo da velha + diretório mapeado ex: minha-webapp#imagens.xml, e adiciona ele no tomcat($TOMCAT_HOME/conf/Catalina/localhost) no server.xml deve funcionar também, veja o [modelo](https://gist.github.com/dilnei/4c9b5ad8865b8c045f7b)

Answer (score 2):

Thiago, tenho uma aplicação semelhante e faço dessa forma:

```
public void upload(FileUploadEvent event)
{
    UploadedFile uf = event.getFile();
    Tools t = new Tools();
    String nomeArq = t.agora()+"-"+t.trataAcentoString(uf.getFileName());
    this.avaliacao.setAnexo_resp(nomeArq);        
    String path = "";
    // aqui verifico se é linux ou windows
    if(System.getProperties().get("os.name").toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("Linux"))
    {
        path = "/home/workspace/gca/WebContent/resources/files/";
    }
    else
    {
        path = "c://files//avaliacao//";
    }

    File f = new File(path + nomeArq);
    OutputStream os = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    try
    {
        is = uf.getInputstream();
        byte[] b = new byte[is.available()];
        os = new FileOutputStream(f);
        while(is.read(b) > 0)
        {  
            os.write(b);  
        }
        // aqui você pode colcar a gravação do path no BD

        Tools.msgAlert("Alerta", "O arquivo foi enviado corretamente, clique em enviar para concluir a operação.");
    } 
    catch(IOException ex) 
    {  
        Tools.msgErro("Erro", ex.getMessage());  
    } 
    finally 
    {  
        try 
        {  
            os.flush();  
            os.close();  
            is.close();  
        } 
        catch(IOException ex) 
        {  
            Tools.msgErro("Erro", ex.getMessage());
        }  
    }
}
```

Observe os comentários no código, pois verifico antes se estou na minha máquina(desenvolvimento) ou no server(produção) e só depois gravo o arquivo passando o caminho completo pra depois salvar no banco.

gca é o nome da aplicação, posso gravar tanto dentro do projeto ou onde eu quiser passando o path completo.

Comment: Boa noite Aragão. De onde vem essa Classe Tools e este metodo t.agora()? Tentei instancia-la mais só tenho a Classe Tool disponivel.

Comment: Outra pergunta. Quando eu colocar esse meu projeto em um servidor na web, esta pasta(por exemplo a variavel path = "c://files//avaliacao//"; passada por você) onde será salva as imagens pera que ser mudada na 'mão'? Ou teria como eu criar um path relativo, como é normal de se fazer com o php por exemplo ?